# Unable to make glib-2.28.0

Tags: glib

```
Making all in gmodule
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu_abhi/Desktop/C Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/gmodule'
make  all-am
**make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu_abhi/Desktop/C Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/gmodule'
  CC     gmodule.lo
  CCLD   libgmodule-2.0.la
/bin/sed: can't read Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/glib/libglib-2.0.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/glib/libglib-2.0.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[3]: *** [libgmodule-2.0.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu_abhi/Desktop/C Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/gmodule'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu_abhi/Desktop/C Dependencies/glib-2.28.0/gmodule'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu_abhi/Desktop/C Dependencies/glib-2.28.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2**
```

Answer (score 2):

`libtool` does not handle directory names with spaces very well. Even [BIND10 came across it](http://bind10.isc.org/ticket/1041) a little while ago.

Rename `/C Dependencies/` to remove the whitespace.